# changing backcolor of the XtraGridView cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, xtragrid

HEllo friends

I want to change the background color of the **DevXpress's XtraGridView's particular cell.**

And the cell must be current focused  cell.

How to do this? can anybody help me in resolving this problem?

thanx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should help

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758

In the example, I would look at this particular code.

Imports DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowStyle(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowStyle
    Dim View As GridView = sender
    If (e.RowHandle >= 0) Then
        Dim category As String = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns("Category"))
        If category = "Beverages" Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Salmon
            e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.SeaShell
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This code seemed to help the situation of helping the programming change the backcolor of two categoris of Bevarage.

Please comment if I made a mistake

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166372/vb-net-xtragrid-change-cell-color-after-its-value-is-edited