# VB.NET XtraGrid Change cell color after its value is edited

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, devexpress

How can I change the XtrsGrid's (GridControl) cell background after its value has been updated/changed/edited?

Can I do it in following event:

```
AddHandler grdView.RowCellStyle, AddressOf grdView_RowCellStyle
```

But this changes the color of whole Grid cells.

```
Private Sub grdView_RowCellStyle(sender As Object, e As RowCellStyleEventArgs)
    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** I need to turn every cell color change whenever a cell value is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it in the following way!

1. you need to handle two events:

   - `GridView.CellValueChanged`
   - `GridView.CustomDrawCell`
2. You need to keep track of every changed cell's indices. So, we need a **List**

Create a class and three fields in it.

```
Public Class UpdatedCell 
  'UC means UpdatedCll
  Public Property UCFocusedRow As Integer
  Public Property UCFocusedColumnIndex As Integer
  Public Property UCFieldName As String

  Public Sub New()
    UCFocusedRow = -1
    UCFocusedColumnIndex = -1
    UCFieldName = String.Empty
  End Sub

End Class
```

Initialize the list in your `Form1_Load` function.

```
Public lst As List(Of UpdatedCell) = New List(Of UpdatedCell)()
```

Now, in `GridView.CellValueChanged` event, do the following:

```
Private Sub grdView_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs)

    Dim currCell As New UpdatedCell
    currCell.UCFocusedRow = e.RowHandle
    currCell.UCFocusedColumnIndex = e.Column.AbsoluteIndex
    currCell.UCFieldName = e.Column.FieldName

    lst.Add(currCell)

End Sub
```

Now, do the following in `GridView.CustomDrawCell` event:

```
Private Sub grdView_CustomDrawCell(sender As Object, e As RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs)

    Dim prevColor As Color = e.Appearance.BackColor

    For Each c As UpdatedCell In lst
        If e.RowHandle = c.UCFocusedRow And
        e.Column.AbsoluteIndex = c.UCFocusedColumnIndex And
        e.Column.FieldName = c.UCFieldName Then

            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow

        Else
            If Not e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow Then
                e.Appearance.BackColor = prevColor
            End If

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Note that the argument `e As RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs` contains all required information. We just need to care of edited cells indices because `GridView.CustomDrawCell` calls every time row/column focus is changed.

See the result.

**Before**
[image]

And **After**
[image]

**NOTE** that yellow cells have different values that I changed using inline/inplace editor.

Thanks